# How correct share of files android 11

Tags: android, file, kotlin, exception, android-intent

I try to share of files in android 11,but i get an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE flg=0x10 pkg=ru.alexanderkozlovskiy.test (has extras) } in ru.alexanderkozlovskiy.test.ActivityMain$loadReciever$1@bbd5a77
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1572)
at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown Source:2)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7861)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:600)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10415 does not have permission to content://downloads/all_downloads/1199 [user 0] [prefix]
```

You can see my code on https://github.com/AlexandrKozlovskiy/share_issue. Thanks everybody for any help.

Comment: I reported issue to google https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190787890

Comment: You must have permission to access URI of any files stored in Downloads. Details https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing

Comment: @Ananta Raha I have write/read external storage permission,but it not works. I haven't any example,how to share of files from downloads folder in android 11.

Comment: I noticed,what crash happens,if i add flag FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION to intent. But without this flag any app can't attach my file.

Comment: You should post your code here. Dont expect us to follow that link. Further you did not tell what the user and your code should do. Start with that!

Comment: And tell which statement causes that exception. We kniw nothing if you do not inform us.

Comment: @blackapps exception hapens in startActivityForResult.